# tabPanel's tabBar (left, right) scroll icons in modern

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6, tabpanel

In extjs 6.5.2 classic when a `tab` overflows the `tabBar` a set of scroll icons is being created on the left and right of the `tabBar`.

It seems that the same functionality is not implemented in extjs 6.5.2 modern.

**extjs 6.5.2 classic example**

```
Ext.create('Ext.tab.Panel', {
width: 300,
height: 200,
activeTab: 0,
scrollable: true,
items: [
    {
        title: 'Tab 1',
        bodyPadding: 10,
        html : 'A simple tab'
    },
    {
        title: 'Tab 2',
        html : 'Another one'
    },
    {
        title: 'Tab 3',
        html : 'Another one'
    },
    {
        title: 'Tab 4',
        html : 'Another one'
    },
    {
        title: 'Tab 5',
        html : 'Another one'
    },
    {
        title: 'Tab 666666666666666666666666666666666666666666',
        html : 'Another one'
    }
],
renderTo : Ext.getBody()
});
```

**extjs 6.5.2 modern example**

```
Ext.create('Ext.TabPanel', {
fullscreen: true,
tabBarPosition: 'top',
tabBar: {
  scrollable: true  //makes the tabBar scrollable when the device is tablet. No scroll icons created though.
},
items: [
    {
        title: 'Home',
        iconCls: 'home',
        html: 'Home Screen'
    },
    {
        title: 'Contact 1',
        iconCls: 'user',
        html: 'Contact Screen'
    },
    {
        title: 'Contact 2',
        iconCls: 'user',
        html: 'Contact Screen'
    },
    {
        title: 'Contact 3',
        iconCls: 'user',
        html: 'Contact Screen'
    },
    {
        title: 'Contact 4',
        iconCls: 'user',
        html: 'Contact Screen'
    },
    {
        title: 'Contact 5',
        iconCls: 'user',
        html: 'Contact Screen'
    },
    {
        title: 'Contact 6666666666666666666666666',
        iconCls: 'user',
        html: 'Contact Screen'
    }
]
});
```

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. There was an Overflow Scroller Example Tabs in [kitchensink](http://examples.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/examples/kitchensink/?modern#overflow-tabs).

Silly me.

Posting it in order to help someone with the same problem.

```
Ext.create('Ext.TabPanel', {
    requires: [
        'Ext.layout.overflow.Scroller'
    ],
    fullscreen: true,
    shadow: 'true',
    tabBar: {
        layout: {
            pack: 'start',
            overflow: 'scroller'
        }
    },
    defaults: {
        scrollable: true,
        layout: 'center',
        //userCls: 'card',
        tab: {
            minWidth: 100
        }
    },
    items: [
        {
            title: 'Home',
            iconCls: 'home',
            html: 'Home Screen'
        },
        {
            title: 'Contact 1',
            iconCls: 'user',
            html: 'Contact Screen'
        },
        {
            title: 'Contact 2',
            iconCls: 'user',
            html: 'Contact Screen'
        },
        {
            title: 'Contact 3',
            iconCls: 'user',
            html: 'Contact Screen'
        },
        {
            title: 'Contact 4',
            iconCls: 'user',
            html: 'Contact Screen'
        },
        {
            title: 'Contact 5',
            iconCls: 'user',
            html: 'Contact Screen'
        },
        {
            title: 'Contact 6666666666666666666666666',
            iconCls: 'user',
            html: 'Contact Screen'
        }
    ]
    });
```